# What does "URL-safe" mean?

Tags: json, http, authentication, web, jwt

The definition for JSON Web Tokens (JWT, see [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519)) says that it is a "URL-safe means of representing claims to be transferred between two parties".

I'm wondering, what does it mean if something is URL-safe?
As far as I know, JWT are not passed around as part of the URL. Is it just that, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later in the RFC it says:

> A JWT is represented as a sequence of URL-safe parts separated by
> period ('.') characters.  Each part contains a base64url-encoded
> value.

This, combined with the RFC not specifying some other meaning explicitly, suggests it means simply "safe to put in a URL" (e.g., doesn't have unencoded `/` or `?` or `&` characters, etc.).

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. It's all about making the transport of the character sequence as simple as possible.